# Is a corresponding CSS necessary for a js functionality to work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use `bootstrap-collapse.js` and it seems to work only when I include the `bootstrap-min.css` but as soon as I include the CSS, my whole site looks messy. How can I use Bootstrap functionality (Carousel, Collapse etc) without applying the CSS? Or is it not possible?

Comment: If you have no CSS for the JS, the JS logic will work just fine, but you will be adding and removing CSS classes that contains 0 info, therefore no changes will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Yes.  Collapse in particular is dependent upon the collapse, in and collapsing classes for its transitions.  Just copy out the classes that you need and add them to your custom css.  It looks to me that these are the ones that are needed.

**If you're using UI Bootstrap 0.13, you have to make sure to add ngAnimate for the transitions.**

```
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
.collapse.in {
  display: block;
}
tr.collapse.in {
  display: table-row;
}
tbody.collapse.in {
  display: table-row-group;
}
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  -o-transition-property: height, visibility;
     transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.35s;
     transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease;
     transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Comment: I think I like this approach because I already have a 'main.css' and an entire site is using it. So, copying from boorstrap.css to my main css might be easier. How do I use an inspector ? is it a browser plugin ?

Comment: I could see the element css by right clicking on it and choosing 'inspect element', I see that some elements are struck out in the inspector, what does it mean ?

Comment: Struck out means those rules are being overridden by a more specific rule.  You just need to focus on the ones from bootstrap.css (not your main.css or user agent applied styles).  You can copy the entire rule right out of the developer tools and paste it into you main.css.  Remember that where you place it (at the end or at the beginning of your styles) will determine whether those style will override your styles or not. Hint: put them before your styles. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

D.J.,

The short answer is that yes, you do need to include bootstrap-min.css for bootstrap-collapse.js to work properly.

Once you've included it, there are a few tricks to keep bootstrap from messing up the existing CSS on your site.

The most basic approach is to use more creative CSS class names for your own CSS. For example, bootstrap uses the class name "container" to create a responsive fixed width div.  So to avoid a conflict you could just use something different for your own container class, eg "DJs-container".

You can also use nested css classes in conjunction with CSS IDs to help avoid this.  Here's an article that might help you:  https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/